# Node JS Express routing with method-override. Can someone explain why _method=DELETE works with my router using route.post, but not route.delete?

Tags: node.js, express

app.js

```
const methodOverride = require ('method-override');
const app = express();
// Method Override Midware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Router

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
// Pass all routes through adminController
const adminController = require('../controllers/adminController');

router.route('/posts/delete/:id')
    .post(adminController.deletePost);
    //.delete(adminController.deletePost);
```

HTML

```
<form action="/admin/posts/delete/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete Post</button>
</form>
```

I spent a good while trying to figure this out and it turns out the solution for a successful deletion was to remove route.delete and replace it with route.post in my router. But I don't understand why this works and .delete doesn't. As far as I know, HTML forms can only GET and POST, but I assumed method-override would circumnavigate this and let me type .delete directly. So now I'm confused as to whether it's the import for override that's not working properly, or if it's working fine and I still need to .post every time regardless and just change the endpoint's method in my HTML?

Thank you

Comment: because the html form does a post request.. and `router.post` listens for post requests ;-;

Comment: Thanks @TheBombSquad, so if I wanted a delete request so my router could explicitly do .delete, I couldn't have my html form do a delete request could I?

Comment: well try turning the form action line to `<form action="/admin/posts/delete/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="post">` then try `.delete` is all I'm saying ;-;

Comment: @TheBombSquad interesting, that's exactly how I had it and running a .delete in my router wouldn't work. Maybe the plugin didn't install properly in my IDE. .post works fine but I would've rather had .delete.